# Find the number of syllables through BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to programming and is currently trying to learn python. My objective is to use web scraping, or more specifically BeautifulSoup to grab the syllables of a word on dictionary.com to use as part of a larger code. Here's what I have so far:

```
def count_syllables(keyword):
    url = 'http://dictionary.com/browse/{}'.format(keyword)
    web_object = requests.get(url)
    text = web_object.text
    text = text.encode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    div = [div for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class':"waypoint-wrapper header-row header-first-row"})]
    span = [div.find(name='span') for div in div]

    return span

#output: [<span class="me" data-syllable="syl·la·ble">syllable</span>]
```

This only returns the span tag in the html source but not the syllable itself. For example, I'm looking to scrape "syl·la·ble" from inputting the word "syllable" into the search bar on dictionary.com. However, my code is only returning the whole span tag. When I try other methods from watching youtube videos, I keep getting empty lists. So my question is: How would I go about just grabbing the syl·la·ble part in the span tag?

Comment: so your expected output is `syl·la·ble` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extent your span tag and use `data-syllable` attribute :

```
>>> span[0]['data-syllable']
'syl·la·bus'
```

Comment: Thanks @emptybladder, appreciate your spirit